# GSM PDU decoding algorithm behaves weirdly

Tags: c

Hello guys i have improved my code.. 
This code works fine for any number of characters but i am getting a problem when i pass symbols like "~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+]}[{'";:.,>" and there is no output. if i pass only characters and numbers i get the output as desired.
can anyone help me with this.
thanks in advance here is my code.

Here is my code. now i have dynamically allocated array before passing it to functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void OriginalHex(int *buffer,int size,char *string)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(string[i] >= '0' && string[i] < 'A')
            buffer[i] = string[i] - '0';
        else if (string[i] >= 'A')
            buffer[i] = string[i] - 'A' + 10;
    }
}

void PackingTheHex(int *hex,int size,int *string)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (i=0,j=0;i<size;i+=2,j++)
        hex[j] = string[i]<<4 | string[i+1];
}


void HexToDec(int *newHex,int len,int *string)
{
    int i=0,j,temp=0x00,l;
    int mask = 0xFF;

    for (i=0,j=0,l=0;i<len/2;i++,j++,l++)
    {
        if(j==8)
        {
            newHex[l] = temp & 0x7f;
            temp = temp>>7;
            j=1;
            l+=1;
        }
        newHex[l] = ((string[i] & (mask>>j+1)) << j) | temp;
        temp = string[i] >> (7-j);
    }
}




int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char userString[512];

    printf("\nEnter 8-Bit Packed Form String: ");
    gets(userString);
    printf("\n\nYou have Entered %s",userString);

    int stringLen = strlen(userString);

    printf("\n\nOringinal Hex: ");
    int *hex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*stringLen);
    OriginalHex(hex,stringLen,userString);
    for (i=0;i<stringLen;i++)
        printf("%d ",hex[i]);

    printf("\n\nPacking The Hex: ");
    int *newHex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*stringLen);
    PackingTheHex(newHex,stringLen,hex);
    for (i=0;i<stringLen/2;i++)
        printf("%d ",newHex[i]);
    free(hex);


    printf("\n\nHex to Decimal Values are: ");
    int *decHex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*stringLen);
    HexToDec(decHex,stringLen,newHex);
    stringLen = stringLen + stringLen/8;
    for (i=0;i<stringLen/2+1;i++)
        printf("%d ",decHex[i]);
    free(newHex);

    char *ASCIIchar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*stringLen);
    for (i=0;i<stringLen/2+1;i++)
        ASCIIchar[i] = (char)decHex[i];
    ASCIIchar[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n\nOriginal sentence is: %s",ASCIIchar);
    free(decHex);
    free(ASCIIchar);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PackingToHex you return a local variable with automatic storage duration:

```
int* PackingToHex(int *string,int len)
{
    int newHex[512];
    ...
    return (&newHex[0]);
}
```

The lifetime of newHex ceases with return from the function and the storage space is subject to reusage, usually on the process stack. The function `HexToDec()` suffers from the very same problem.

A quick fix, depending on the circumstances, could be to use static storage:

```
static int newHex[512];
```

In this case, the lifetime of newHex is not limited, but you have to keep in mind, that there is only *one* storage, which will be overwritten on each new call to `PackingToHex()`. If this is a problem, you will have to make use of dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()/free()`.

As a side note: A compiler will usually warn for this kind of errors if warnings are enabled properly, you can avoid many errors by listening to your compiler.

Comment: as u have said i have overcome with the warnings and it works fine but with only characters and numbers. if i provide symbols it doesn't give any output.. please suggest some ideas

Comment: check the question for the modified code. i have edited previous one

Comment: @DevjeetMandal As far as I interpret your code, only hex digits (0-9 A-F) are sensible inputs to your program,

Comment: So what should i do if i need symbols too.?

Comment: and suppose a symbol semicolon it's hex value is 0x3B.. it should decode ryt?

Comment: @DevjeetMandal Ok, what exactly is your input now? The semicolon itself or `3B`? Please provide a real transcript of your input, the actual output and the output you expect to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: input:  00400023005F002D002B00280029002F002A00220027003A003B0021003F002E002C003C003E005B005D007B007D003D005C0025007E0060007C (only the text part not pdu part)  output: Nil Desired output: @#_-+()/*"':;!?.,<>[]{}=\%~`|

Comment: this is for symbols. if i provide alphanumeric values like input: E8329BFD4697D9EC37BACC66BFD16536FB8D2EB3D96F7499CD7EA3CB6CF61B5D66B3DFE8329BFD4697D9EC37BACC66BFD16536FB0D  output: hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello (as expected)

Comment: @-Ctx My input is 8-bit packed PDU message. My output will be ASCII values.

Comment: @DevjeetMandal The problem are the zero-bytes at the start and sprayed all over your string (00), each denoting the end of string.

Comment: @-Ctx PDU formats will contains many attributes like Phone number n all.. i.m just taking the part which is my actual text.

Comment: @-Ctx Yes i followed that so i deleted that 00's from the string and made it like thsi input: 40235F2D2B28292F2A22273A3B213F2E2C3C3E5B5D7B7D3D5C257E607C  output: @F|j2J/9"gN?\0acgV.{zuaUD0  Desired Output: @#_-+()/*"':;!?.,<>[]{}=\%~`|

Comment: @DevjeetMandal If this is your desired output, then you have to skip the HexToDec function, since this function makes the 7 to 8 bit conversion. However, the data 40235F2D2B28292F2A22273A3B213F2E2C3C3E5B5D7B7D3D5C257E607C _is_ already 8 bit, so this conversion does not apply here

Comment: @-Ctx i am not sure what you are asking me to do. All my inputs are 8-bit data only(packed 8-bit) and i am converting it to 7-bit data(technically 8th bit MSB will be 0) and HexToDec does that for me and provide me with decimal value which i further convert to ASCII. How can i eliminate this function for Symbols?